# nodejs express/routes and mysql LOGIN PAGE

Tags: mysql, node.js, login-page

Just started learning Node last week and I am trying to create a login page by using express and mySQL.

I have watched few tutorial videos on the internet, and came up with a set of codes below. I can run this code with no error pops-up, but there is a little problem that the server didn't reDirect to other page after I pressed the login button.

I wondering if there is something wrong in my Front End Part or I have missed some part. I truly hope you guys could give me a hand as I have tried about 3 days to get pass this stage.

Thanks

please see code:

**routes/login.ejs:**

```
<input id="txtUserName" name="txtUserName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" />
</div>
<input id="txtUserPwd" name="txtUserPwd" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
</div>
<button class="btn btn-default submit" href="/users">Log in</button>
```

**views/login.js:**

```
var express = require('express'),
User = require('../models/user.js'),
router = express.Router(),
crypto = require('crypto'),
title = 'LogIn';


router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('login', {title:title});
});


router.post('/', function(req, res) {
var userName = req.body['txtUserName'],
    userPwd = req.body['txtUserPwd'],
    md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');

User.getUserByUserName(userName, function (err, results) {
    if(results == '') {
        res.locals.error = 'Accounts Not Exist';
        res.render('login',{title:title});
        return;
    }


    userPwd = md5.update(userPwd).digest('hex');
    if(results[0].UserName != userName || results[0].UserPass != userPwd) {
        res.locals.error = 'Wrong User Name or Password';
        res.render('login',{title:title});
        return;
    } else {
        res.locals.username = userName;
        //設定session
        req.session.username = res.locals.username;
        console.log(req.session.username);
        res.redirect('/');
        return;
    }
});
});
module.exports = router;
```

**Models/user.js**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var connection  = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : 'testtest'
});

connection.query('USE myfirstwebapp');

function User(user){
   this.username = user.username;
   this.userpass = user.userpass;
};

User.getUserNumByName = function getUserNumByName(username, callback) {

var cmd = "select COUNT(1) AS num from user info where username = ?";
    connection.query(cmd, [username], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
        connection.release();
        callback(err,result);
    });
};

User.getUserByUserName = function getUserNumByName(username, callback) {
var cmd = "select * from userinfo where username = ?";
    connection.query(cmd, [username], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return;
        }
        connection.release();
        callback(err,result);
    });
 };
```

Comment: do you have any javascript or frontend stuff, where you send data from your login page to the node.js backend? Plus you send a `href="/users"` but in your backend I only see `/` and nothing with `/users`

Comment: @KingReload Thanks for the reply sir, I this is the Front End I have as I am trying to see if I can login, and I have changed href="/users" is a dashboard if login success. May I know if I am doing my backEnd Right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6236721/7707749 you should take a look at this then.

Comment: @SimoneRene, did you ever resolve this?